# Show $\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert \le \delta$ iff there are random variables $X,Y$ with distributions $\mu,\nu$ so that $P(X \neq Y) \le \delta$.

Tags: probability-theory

> Show that $\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert \le \delta$ if and only if there are random variables $X$ and $Y$ with distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ so that $P(X \neq Y) \le \delta$.

FYI, this is Exercise 3.6.1 from the Durrett Probability (fifth edition) textbook. Also the textbook specifies $\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert \le 2\delta$, but I believe the $2\delta$ is a mistake and should be $\delta$.

\begin{align*}
    \lVert \mu - \nu \rVert \le \delta \iff P(X \neq Y) \le \delta
\end{align*}

We define total variation distance between two measures $\mu, \nu$ as follows, where $\mathcal{R}$ are the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align*}
  \lVert \mu - \nu \rVert &=\sup_{A \in \mathcal{R}} \lvert \mu(A) - \nu(A) \rvert \\
\end{align*}

If $f,g$ are density functions corresponding to $\mu, \nu$, then, we have an equivalent and possibly more useful definition of total variation distance:

\begin{align*}
  \lVert \mu - \nu \rVert &= \int_\mathbb{R} \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert \, dx \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    P(X \neq Y) &= \int_\Omega 1_{X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)} \, dP \\
\end{align*}

The standard way to define random variables that have given distributions, is first to get the CDF:

\begin{align*}
    F &: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1] \\
    F(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) \, dy \\
    F(x) &= \mu((-\infty, x]) \\
\end{align*}

Define probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with $\Omega = (0,1)$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{R}$, $P$ be the Lebesgue measure. Then, our corresponding random variable with cumulative distribution function $F$ is:

\begin{align*}
    X &: \Omega \to \mathbb{R} \\
    X(\omega) &= \text{sup} \{ y : F(y) < \omega \} \\
\end{align*}

We can also make.a cdf $G$ corresponding to $\nu$ and $g$ and define a corresponding random variable $Y$.

From there, I'm stuck on what to try next.

Comment: How is $P$ related to $\mu,\nu$?

Comment: @copper.hat OP says "random variables $X$ and $Y$ with distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ " which measn $\mu =P\circ X^{-1}$ and $\mu =P\circ Y^{-1}$.

Comment: You left out that that Durrett is only asking this question for measures defined on a **countable** set $S$. Please edit this necessary into context to your question.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure it should be $\|\mu-\nu\|\le \delta \iff P(X\neq Y)\le \delta$, that is Durrett mistakenly included the $2$. For example, with $\delta=0.75$, the condition $\|\mu-\nu\|\le 2\delta$ always holds since total variation is at most one, but $P(X\neq Y)\le 0.75$ does not always hold.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, my professor is asking us to prove the rule both for integer valued variables (countable) and real valued variables (not countable), so I'd like the proof that doesn't assume countability if possible.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, you are right about $2\delta$. I will update the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $(\!\!\impliedby\!)$ direction is the easiest. To do this, take $\|\mu-\nu\|=\sup_A|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|$, and make the replacements
$$
\mu(A)=P(A\times \mathbb Z)=P(A\times A)+P(A\times A^c)\\
\nu(A)=P(\mathbb Z\times A)=P(A\times A)+P(A^c\times A)\\
$$
to conclude $\|\mu-\nu\|=\sup_A |\mu(A\times A^c)-\nu(A^c\times A)|$. How does $|\mu(A\times A^c)-\nu(A^c\times A)|$ relate to $P(X\neq Y)$?

For the $(\!\!\implies\!\!)$ direction, you need to construct random variables for which $P(X\neq Y)=\|\mu-\nu\|$. This part is quite hard; I cannot give hints for coming up with the construction, but I will leave proving the construction works to you.

First, let us show how to do this in the case that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures defined on $\mathbb Z$. It turns out the a joint distribution which works is the one defined by
$$
P(X=x,Y=y)=
\begin{cases}
\min(\mu(x),\nu(y))& x=y\\
\frac{(\mu(x)-\nu(x))^+(\nu(y)-\mu(y))^+}{\|\mu-\nu\|} & x\neq y
\end{cases}\tag 1
$$
Recall that $x^+=\max(x,0)$. I suggest you take the time to carefully verify that this distribution has the correct marginals, and that it satisfies $P(X\neq Y)=\|\mu-\nu\|$. It helps to define $A=\{z\in \mathbb Z\mid \mu(z)\le \nu(z)\}$, and to verify $P(X=z)=\mu(z)$ for $z\in A$ and $z\notin A$, separately.

What about the general case? Things are made tricky by the fact that we cannot use probability mass functions any more. Instead, we will find a common measure that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to, and take the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ and $\nu$ with respect to both.

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures on $\Bbb R$ (or any measurable space). Let $\lambda$ be the measure $\mu+\nu$, and let $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\qquad g(y)=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}
$$
These derivatives will serve the role of the missing pmfs. We will define a measure $\pi$ on $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ as follows. We proceed in two parts (that resemble the two cases in $(1)$).

- Consider the function $h(z)=\min(f(z),g(z))$. Then $h(z)\,d\lambda$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$ (where the measure of $A$ is $\int_A h(z)\,d\lambda$). Take the pushforward of this measure under the diagonal inclusion map $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ to get a measure $\pi_1$ on $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ supported on the diagonal.
- Consider the function $$k(x,y)=\frac{(f(x)-g(x))^+\cdot (g(y)-f(y))^+}{\|\mu-\nu\|}.$$ Then $$\pi_2= k(x,y)\mu(dx)\nu(dy)$$ defines a measure on $\mathbb R\times \Bbb R$. To be clear, $\pi_2(A)=\int_A k(x,y)\mu(dx)\nu(dy)$.

Finally, it turns out that $\pi_1+\pi_2$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ for which $P(X\neq Y)=\|\mu-\nu\|$.